# Can't call firebase function inside firebase.once

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

In my code I'm trying to update the database after getting the value of a node however it's not working

```
firebase.database().ref('/likr/'+'xx').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   var myLikes = snapshot.val();
   if(myLikes === null) {
      //do nothing
   } else {
       var likedMe = myLikes.hasOwnProperty(term.user);
       if (likedMe) {
          console.log("IM HERE");
          firebase.database().ref('/mues/'+'value').update({
            liked: "true"
          });
       }
   };
});
```

I'm getting the log "IM HERE" however the firebase update function does not call, I'm using React Native, I even tried calling a function outside to trigger the firebase update, that still didn't work and I also tried calling a redux action that would call the firebase update function and the redux action didn't seem to be called at all, however the update function on its own outside the .once function works fine.

Help?

Comment: So this is code you're running in Cloud Functions for Firebase?  If so, can you show your entire function?

Comment: It's running on the client side not Cloud functions, in the React Native code.

Comment: I found a workaround, I used the .on instead of .once so that I could keep listening and this way I was able to call the update function inside, perhaps the .once stopped the call